# Cannot read proprety length of undefined?

Tags: javascript, button, types, onclick

I created a function which takes a string I wrote in an html textbox and prints the length of that string in the next textbox (the first textbox is the 5th one on my HTML page)

```
function StringLength(){

var aInput = document.querySelectorAll("[text='text']");
var sResult = aInput[5].length;
aInput[6].value = (sResult);



}
```

I then used the onClick method to print on the 6th textbox the length of the string by calling the function

```
<label><input type="button" value="Trouve" onClick="LongueurChaine()"/></label>

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
at LongueurChaine (demo.js:54)
at HTMLInputElement.onclick (gabarit.html:85)
LongueurChaine @ demo.js:54
onclick @ gabarit.html:85
```

I get this everytime I try to click on the button..? Is there an easier way of achieving this?

Comment: You should add the tag for the language you're asking about. It looks like you're inquiring about JavaScript, but give everybody some help! (You'll also reach the right people easier.)

Answer (score 0):

If it is the 5th textbox, its index in the resulting array must be 4.

Also, your selector was [text='text'], i guess you mean [type='text'].

```
function StringLength(){    
   var aInput = document.querySelectorAll("[type='text']");
   var sResult = aInput[4].length;
   aInput[5].value = (sResult);    
}
```

Comment: Is it still exactly the same error? Can you provide some code for the textbox?

Comment: This is the HTML code for the 2nd part of my texboxes, and yes it's still the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
                <div> 
                <fieldset>
                    <label>String : <input type="text" name="Nom"/></label>

                    <label>Length : <input type="text" name="Nom"/></label>

                    <label>'x' : <input type="text" name="Nom"/></label>

                    <label>Position of 'x' : <input type="text" name="Nom"/></label>

                    <label>Integer : <input type="text" name="Nom"/></label>

                    <label>char : <input type="text" name="Nom"/></label>

                    <label>Extraction : <input type="text" name="Nom"/></label>


                </fieldset>

                      <fieldset>

                    <label><input type="reset" value="Efface"/></label> 
                          <br>
                    <label><input type="button" value="Trouve" onClick="StringLength()"/></label> 


                     </fieldset>
                </div
```